# Upsert document while pushing to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have the following Schema:

```
var TestSchema = db.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
    data: []
},
{ strict: false });

var Test = db.model('Test', TestSchema);
```

Notice it is `strict: false`. I would like to be able to `upsert` new documents. The thing is, I don't want the `data` array to be overwritten, but rather for new documents to be pushed into it.

For example, assuming this is an existing document:

```
{ name: "hello world",
  data: 
   [ { one: '123',
       two: '456' } ]
}
```

And I wish to `upsert` this one:

```
{ name: "hello world",
  new_field: "to be updated"
  data: 
   [ { one: 'pushed to the array',
       two: 'xyz' } ]
}
```

The expected result would be:

```
{ name: "hello world",
  new_field: "to be updated"
  data: 
   [ { one: 'abc',
       two: 'xyz' },
     { one: 'pushed to the array',
       two: 'xyz'} ]
}
```

To explicitly explain: the document already exists, so it should be updated. The new field `new_field` is updated. However instead of overwriting the existing `data` array (as a regular update would), we push the new documents to the array.

I have a very ugly working version that uses three calls to achieve this, which is completely unusable (asynchronous -> duplicates get inserted instead of updated when you throw many queries at the same time).

Can this actually be achieved in Mongoose?

Answer (score 2):

You can use $push like this:

```
{$set:{ new_field: "to be updated" },$push:{data:{ one: 'pushed to the array',two: 'xyz' }}}
```

Update query would be:

```
db.test.update({name: "hello world"}, {
$set:{ new_field: "to be updated" } 
$push:{data:{ one: 'pushed to the array',two: 'xyz' }}});
```

Comment: Can this work if I don't know  the names of the fields? Say I have a `Test` called `test1` and I don't know which non-`strict` fields it has, and I don't know the exact structure of the document pushed to the array (or how many documents need to be pushed to the array for that matter).

Comment: You can use _id of mongodb

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding. If it's not too much, could you perhaps show me an example where you use `$set` and `$push` without using the words `new_field`, `one` and `two`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped point me in the right direction and I've found a solution that works perfectly for my case. I've posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this in a nice and clean way:

```
// Let 'test' be a Test object who's values we want to upsert
test = { 
  name: "hello world",
  new_field: "to be updated"
  data: 
   [ { one: 'pushed to the array',
       two: 'xyz' } ]
}

// We do this to 'test'
test['$addToSet'] = {
  'data': { '$each': test.data }
};
delete test.data

// 'test' now looks like this
// test = { 
//   'name': 'hello world',
//   'new_field': 'to be updated'
//   '$addToSet': { data: { '$each': [Object] } }
// }

// And this is how we upsert 'test'
// while also upserting values into the data array
Test.findOneAndUpdate({
    name: test.name,
}, test, { upsert: true, new: true }, function(error, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});
```

I've been looking how to do this for a while, and I didn't find it straightforwardly explained anywhere, but it works and it's useful.